# Adding JSON objects to list in c#, help needed

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, unity-game-engine

Writing a game which has a JSON database that has 250 objects.I am using Unity to build the game and C#. I created a Class for the Word object, class for reading the JSON and a class/gameobject to load the data. The console debug log will show my JSON file. But the gameobject is empty and has only 1 element.

//Filereader

```
  public class JsonFileReader 

public static string LoadJsonAsResource(string path)
{
    string jsonFilePath = path.Replace(".json", "");
    TextAsset loadedJsonfile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(jsonFilePath);
    return loadedJsonfile.text;
}
```

// My Datafile

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DataJson
{
    public int catNr;
    public string category;
    public int wordNr;
    public string est;
    public string eng;
    public string fin;
    public string esp;
    public string ger;
    public string swe;
}
```

//Dataloader for gameobject

```
public class DataLoader : MonoBehaviour

public List<DataJson> MyData;

void Awake()
{

    MyData = new List<DataJson>();
    LoadData("data.json");

}


public void LoadData(string path)
{
    string myLoadedItem = JsonFileReader.LoadJsonAsResource(path);
    Debug.Log(myLoadedItem);
    DataJson myData = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataJson>(myLoadedItem);
    MyData.Add(myData);

}
```

}

//Json File

```
"words": [
    {
        "catNr": "1",
        "category": "Kodu- ja taluloomad",
        "wordNr": "1",
        "est": "Koer",
        "eng": "Dog",
        "fin": "Koira",
        "esp": "Perro",
        "ger": "der Hund",
        "swe": "Hund"
    },
```

[image: Unity Empty GameObject]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd suggest using JSON parser from [that asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347) instead of Unity's `JsonUtility`. It works a bit better and will possibly help to avoid some trouble in the future. It's based on well known [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

Personally I always use some automating tool, ex. [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), to generate C# classes from JSONs. After pasting slightly fixed JSON (added missing brackets and parenthesis):

```
{
    "words": [
        {
            "catNr": "1",
            "category": "Kodu- ja taluloomad",
            "wordNr": "1",
            "est": "Koer",
            "eng": "Dog",
            "fin": "Koira",
            "esp": "Perro",
            "ger": "der Hund",
            "swe": "Hund"
        }
    ]
}
```

and generating, it quickly shows that apart from `Word` class there should be some `RootObject` class which contains `List` of `Word`s:

```cs
public class Word
{
    public string catNr { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string wordNr { get; set; }
    public string est { get; set; }
    public string eng { get; set; }
    public string fin { get; set; }
    public string esp { get; set; }
    public string ger { get; set; }
    public string swe { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Word> words { get; set; }
}
```

(You can also rename `RootObject` to ex. `WordList` or whatever you like)

That means that in order to parse this JSON correctly, you should pass `RootObject` as type to `JsonUtility.FromObject<T>` (or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` if you move to Json.NET):

```cs
RootObject myData = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(myLoadedItem);
Word singleWord = myData.words[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and fast answer, and sharing tips .

Comment: @MaitKaasik You're welcome :) If it solved your problem, mark is as an answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get the whole json then you should specify it so.

```
List<DataJson> myData = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<DataJson>>(myLoadedItem);
```

For it to be more right then you should create a class that match your json, im amazed that you could event get an object returned from json. see the example below.

```
Public class DataJsonContainer {

public List<DataJson> Words { get; set; }

}
```

and then

```
 DataJsonContainer myData = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataJsonContainer>(myLoadedItem);
```

I read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) and `FromJson` return only the `T` and not a `List<T>`